# Registered Trademark symbol not coming correctly in java, jstl

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding

I have a situation here:

I have a page which is using to show data from server, in which the content has some special characters as Registered Trademark and stuff.I am using java, jsp, jstl in my code.

I have a local development environment in which it works on Windows XP + Tomcat 6/ Weblogic 9.2.3
but when i deploy this same code on Production servers it has a combination of Linux & Weblogic 9.2.3

the registered trademark symbol comes as ỳ 
If i do a explicit UTF-8 encoding in my java code where data comes in BufferedReader object :

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in**,"UTF-8"**));
```

the registered trademark symbol comes as rectangular box type special character(can't understand it) :D

I added a code in jsp

<%@pageEncoding...."UTF-8" %> - dont remember the exact line

But it didnt work for me... i added the above line in my parent as well as iframed jsp it showed me a square box & "?" but no registered trademark.....                                               My Production Server is running on Linux and my local development server is on Windows is that a BIG difference as such to not show the registered trademark.

Thanks in advance...

--
El Nino

Comment: first of all, you should check if your browser is correctly interpreting the source as UTF8. With Firefox, you could use "View > Character Encoding > UTF8" to force encoding. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: btw, with Chrome it would be "Wrench > Tools > Encoding > UTF8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the response encoding to UTF-8 as well. On a per-JSP basis you can do that by adding the following line to the top:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC but it didnt work for me... i added the above line in my parent as well as iframed jsp it showed me a square box & "?" but no registered trademark.....

Comment: Then the data was not originally saved/encoded in UTF-8. How are you saving the data? In a DB? Is the DB table configured as UTF-8? Or in a file? Was it saved with `OutputStreamWriter` as UTF-8? Or was it created by some text editor? Did you pick the *Save As* option to choose the encoding? Etc. See also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html